# Windows 8 create share on mounted ISO at startup

Tags: windows-8, mount, boot, iso-image

I have recently found someone who posted a registry setting that auto mounts an ISO on Windows 8 Pro at start-up.
This is great because it allows me to mount my Office install disc which I can then use when setting up new laptops and PCs, and install over the network.

The only issue I have found is that the share is not auto created after the image is mounted, and I am assuming this is because the service that creates shares (I think it is the server service?), is started before the image is mounted.

Is there a script I can run at start up that creates the share once the image is mounted, or can I make the service dependent on something else to allow it to create automatically.

Comment: If you want to share the data for prolonged periods of time, why don't you extract the ISO contents and share those permanently?

Comment: I quite like the idea of having the image mounted, as I also use this virtual drive for some of my Hyper-V machines. Just find it is easier that way I guess.